# Heap corruption detected (String makes heap corruption) | C++

Tags: c++, string, heap-corruption

I dont know why this function has made the heap corruption, I'm sure that the function copyFile isn't related to the error. Please check and help me TT

```
    void copyFileToFolder(char* fileName, char* folderName)
{
    char backSlash = '\\';
    char *nameOfFileWithBackSlashInHead = strrchr(fileName, backSlash);
    char *newFileName = strcat(folderName, nameOfFileWithBackSlashInHead);
    FILE* f = fopen(newFileName, "wb");
    if (!f)
    {
        cout << "Folder does't exist";
        return;
    }
    fclose(f);
    copyFile(fileName, newFileName);
}
```

Comment: P/S: The program still work in spite of the heap corruption

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strcat` will append to `folderName` which is problematic. `folderName` is comming from outside and it might result in memory corruption if you write beyond its allocated storage. See `strcat` appends to its first input argument and also returns it.

Change your function signature to

```
void copyFileToFolder(const char* fileName, const char* folderName)
```

and make a new variable to store appended file name.

Comment: i get it, i've made a new variable to store appended file name and it's worked. Thanks